# how do I block a LAMP server from any communication with outside except a whitelist!

Tags: linux, security, apache-2.2, network-protocols, firewall

Hi I want to black my server from any contact with a black list of ips and I would also like to block any domain names if possible, and have it only send http headers back and forth between ip addresses!

I would like to pretty much block any dataleaks to outside except serving the users that have a valid php session! I'm using a lot of code I download just to learn and I dont know where the people who post these have got them from or what kinda backdoors they have put in there so I would like to make sure I'm not gonna get in trouble for using anything I wasn't supposed to because of license and copyright issues!

Answer (score 4):

To block certain IP addresses (or hostnames) from accessing your website, you could use Apache's `Allow` and `Deny` directives, something like what sukru said. But it's often considered more secure to *completely* block *any* communication (not just website access) between the selected IPs and your server - after all, if you have reason enough to keep them from accessing your website, you probably don't want them accessing other stuff on your server either. To enforce that kind of access, you'll have to use IPtables. There are many IPtables references online; I happen to have written [one](http://www.ellipsix.net/geninfo/firewall/index.html) which might be of some use to you. The relevant commands would be

```
iptables -I INPUT --source xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT --destination xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is the IP address you want to block. Run both these commands for each such address.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update httpd.conf (or .htaccess if sufficient options are enabled)

```
<Location /url>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from host1
  Deny from host2
  Deny from *.domain
  ...etc
</Location>
```

From documentation: [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_access.html#order)

> Allow,Deny
>       First, all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or
>   the request is rejected. Next, all
>   Deny directives are evaluated. If any
>   matches, the request is rejected.
>   Last, any requests which do not match
>   an Allow or a Deny directive are
>   denied by default.

Comment: Um... don't you mean `Order deny,allow`? Because what you have would enable communication with all hosts.

Comment: Nope, the documentation specifically says it's the opposite, there is even a table in the linked page which shows the results when both a deny and allow rule matches.

Comment: Huh, I thought I remembered reading otherwise. You're right though.